# Pandas dataframe select rows where a list-column contains a particular string in list

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I've got a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
  molecule            species
0        a              [dog]
1        b       [horse, pig]
2        c         [cat, dog]
3        d  [cat, horse, pig]
4        e     [chicken, pig]
```

and I like to extract a DataFrame containing only thoses rows, that only contain selection =  ['dog']. So the result should look like this:

```
  molecule            species
0        a              [dog]
```

What would be the simplest way to do this?

For testing:

```
selection = ['dog']
df = pd.DataFrame({'molecule': ['a','b','c','d','e'], 'species' : [['dog'], ['horse','pig'],['cat', 'dog'], ['cat','horse','pig'], ['chicken','pig']]})
```

I am only able to find out the options which can extract any column with dog in the list

Comment: Have you tried `df[df.species == [dog]]`?

Comment: Is possible `[dog, dog]` ? Then is selected if `selection = ['dog']` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare sets, it return list with one or multiple lists with only `dog` values:

```
df1 = df[df['species'].apply(lambda x: set(x) == set(selection))]
print (df1)
  molecule species
0        a   [dog]
```

If need select only one value `[dog]` use:

```
df2 = df[df['species'].astype(str).eq(str(selection))]
print (df2)
  molecule species
0        a   [dog]
```

Comment: What about if I want to choose [cat,dog] column contents .

Comment: @startedtocode - use `selection=['dog','cat']`